# $_REQUEST and urldecode

Tags: javascript, php, urldecode

I am creating URL links with request form values (?a=b&c=d) in JavaScript and submitting to a PHP page. I am using encodeURIComponent in JavaScript to properly encode the form information.

I've already tested this and I've found that the values in $_REQUEST are already `urldecode`'d. So I've taken my urldecode calls out of my php, as they are redundant and potentially harmful for some input.

The purpose of this question is just to get some reassurance that I tested this correctly my understanding is correct, and that under normal conditions you don't need to explicitly call urldecode in php.

Comment: @user3783243 This is sufficient for my purposes. I will change over to $_GET as this is actually more informative to what I'm doing. Please submit your answer as an answer and I'll check your solution

Comment: @user3783243 I had temporarily deleted my question while I queried meta.stackoverflow.com as to what to do about your solution to a different question that resolved my issue. From what I read on meta, your answer can stand. So please enter your comment as an answer

Comment: I've moved comment to an answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306270/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-was-resolved-with-a-comment-that-isnt-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is documented that `$_GET` is url decoded. There is no mention of this for the `$_REQUEST` global though.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

> The GET variables are passed through urldecode().

However from https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php:

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE

I think it can be inferred that something like `array_mege` is being used and so the `GET` values will be here decoded as well.

Comment: What you've inferred is what I'd infer also